# How to solve "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to OSError.__format__"?

Tags: python, error-handling, redpitaya

I call in this module into my code, however it causes an error which I do not understand or know how to fix.

Here is the code:

```
except socket.error as e:
        print('SCPI >> connect({:s}:{:d}) failed: {:s}'.format(host, port, e))
```

And here is the error:

```
 File "C:\Users\dweisskopf\Downloads\redpitaya_scpi.py", line 29, in __init__
print('SCPI >> connect({:s}:{:d}) failed: {:s}'.format(host, port, e))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to OSError.__format__
```

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect this is a `python` version issue. What does `python -V` display? Please also [edit] your post to add the appropriate `python` version tag.

Comment: Just print it, without formatting?

Comment: Its part of a library im importing would that still work if I did it without the formatting?